# Concatenate result set in Postgres Query with duplicates removed

Tags: postgresql

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023933/concatcolumn-overpartition-by-group-concatentating-rows-without-grouping), I'm looking for a way to concatenate the results of multiple rows of a query result into a single row, but without retaining duplicates. What I'm trying to do is to match up old data with new data, but in the new data set only one value is permitted, where previously multiple values where.

Currently I can pull the following set of data using a with clause:

```
  id  |  new  |  old
----------------------
 1001 |   x   |   a
 1001 |   x   |   b
 1001 |   x   |   c
 1002 |   y   |   b
 1002 |   y   |   e
 1002 |   y   |   f
 1003 |   z   |   b
 1003 |   z   |   c
 1004 |   z   |   c
```

What I need to pull is more along the lines of:

```
  id  |  new  |  old
----------------------
 1001 |   x   | a,b,c
 1002 |   y   | b,e,f
 1003 |   z   |  b,c
 1004 |   z   |   c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a simple case of grouping id,new:

```
select id, new, string_agg(old, ',' order by old)
from dupes
group by id, new
order by id;
```

SQLFiddl: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49706/1

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I didn't know about that function. I'm still a bit of a newbie to Postgres (nor am I a dedicated dev, I just handle certain minor things for my team), most of what I know is out of necessity and/or casually looking through the Postgres documentation.

Comment: DISTINCT is missing in string_agg(), but it's working for this (unique) dataset. When unique values for "old" are required, you do need DISTINCT.